# Client visibility with two gateways

Tags: routing, router

Our company (WISP company) has a management computer located on one gateway (Gateway A) with multiple routers with redundant routes to a second gateway (Gateway B). The traffic going through Gateway B is not visible through Gateway A when Gateway B is the active route. I'm needing the server to be able to see clients dynamically whether it's going through either gateway. Both Gateway A and Gateway B are controlled by Edge Routers.

EDIT

By gateway I mean a path to the internet. We are running a public webpage on the server as well!

[image: small network diagram]

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'Gateway'?  And what information about the clients does this management computer need to see?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: what do you mean by "see clients dynamically" or what are you trying to do/capture?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the clients need to reach the server, it looks like you would add a static route to the 450-G (non-edge device) pointing the 10.254.254.0/30 network at 10.202.1.1.

If you mean something else by 'see clients dynamically whether it's going through either gateway' like WCCP/etc. then we would need that information to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to syslog the relevant client data to your central management server(s).